# What does 头 mean in 奔头 and 盼头?

Tags: word

Today in my stroll of the campus I saw a post saying 让职业教育有学头，有奔头，有盼头, that highly interested and confused me at the same time, especially the word 头 repeated three times. Does it mean a target, like in a game where a head of an Indian or an animal put before the shooter(by the way, I do not play games myself, that is simply what I imagine to be so)?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like things written on a red banner in big yellow characters

Words have various meanings. We can glean the meaning from the context perhaps. This sounds like propaganda with a complex inference. The writer knows his or her job!

头：事情的开端 beginning
头：物的两端或末梢: middle
头：物的两端或末梢: end

学头：reason for studying: literally study, beginning
奔头：prospects, light at the end of the tunnel: literally rush around time: middle
盼头：hope: literally where you are looking: end

让职业教育有学头，有奔头，有盼头。
Let vocational training have reason (for studying), have prospects, have hope!

Or 学头发：study hair :)

Answer (score 1):

These are slogans used in recent decisions to promote the images and quality of the "vocational education" in China, by the Ministry of Education. Below are my interpretations:

有学**头** - has tangible knowledge/skills **worth** learning. (有 - 致用的教材)

有奔**头** - has a future **worth** pursuing. (有 - 出路/前途/發展的舞台)

有盼**头** - has good prospects **worth** hoping for. (有 - 希望)

**Note:** In these cases, 头 together with the verb that proceeds it forms a noun. Example: 念头 (idea/thought/intention).

[Further reading: 职业教育，要让学生有学头有盼头有奔头](https://www.sohu.com/a/527992668_121118997#:%7E:text=3%E6%9C%887%E6%97%A5%EF%BC%8C%E5%85%A8%E5%9B%BD%E6%94%BF%E5%8D%8F%E5%A7%94%E5%91%98%E3%80%81%E4%B8%8A%E6%B5%B7%E4%B8%AD%E5%8D%8E%E8%81%8C%E6%95%99%E7%A4%BE%E5%B8%B8%E5%8A%A1%E5%89%AF%E4%B8%BB%E4%BB%BB%E8%83%A1%E5%8D%AB%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%EF%BC%8C%E9%AB%98%E8%B4%A8%E9%87%8F%E7%9A%84%E8%81%8C%E4%B8%9A%E6%95%99%E8%82%B2%E5%9F%B9%E5%85%BB%E5%AD%A6%E7%94%9F%EF%BC%8C%E6%97%A2%E8%A6%81%E6%95%99%E5%81%9A%E4%BA%BA%E3%80%81%E4%B9%9F%E8%A6%81%E6%95%99%E5%81%9A%E4%BA%8B%EF%BC%8C%E6%97%A2%E8%A6%81%E5%AD%A6%E6%96%87%E5%8C%96%E3%80%81%E4%B9%9F%E8%A6%81%E5%AD%A6%E6%8A%80%E6%9C%AF%EF%BC%8C%E8%AE%A9%E5%AD%A6%E7%94%9F%E6%97%A2%E6%9C%89%E5%AD%A6%E5%A4%B4%E3%80%81%E5%8F%88%E6%9C%89%E7%9B%BC%E5%A4%B4%E3%80%81%E8%BF%98%E6%9C%89%E5%A5%94%E5%A4%B4%E3%80%82,%E8%81%8C%E4%B8%9A%E6%95%99%E8%82%B2%E8%82%A9%E8%B4%9F%E7%9D%80%E5%9F%B9%E5%85%BB%E5%A4%9A%E6%A0%B7%E5%8C%96%E4%BA%BA%E6%89%8D%E3%80%81%E4%BC%A0%E6%89%BF%E6%8A%80%E6%9C%AF%E6%8A%80%E8%83%BD%E3%80%81%E4%BF%83%E8%BF%9B%E5%B0%B1%E4%B8%9A%E5%88%9B%E4%B8%9A%E7%9A%84%E9%87%8D%E8%A6%81%E8%81%8C%E8%B4%A3%E3%80%82%20%E8%81%8C%E4%B8%9A%E6%95%99%E8%82%B2%E7%9B%B4%E6%8E%A5%E9%9D%A2%E5%AF%B9%E5%AD%A6%E7%94%9F%EF%BC%8C%E5%AF%B9%E5%AD%A6%E7%94%9F%E8%B4%9F%E8%B4%A3%E3%80%81%E8%AE%A9%E5%AD%A6%E7%94%9F%E5%8F%97%E7%9B%8A%E5%B0%B1%E9%9D%9E%E5%B8%B8%E5%85%B3%E9%94%AE%EF%BC%8C%E8%A6%81%E5%8A%AA%E5%8A%9B%E5%81%9A%E5%88%B0%E8%AE%A9%E5%AD%A6%E7%94%9F%E6%9C%89%E5%AD%A6%E5%A4%B4%E3%80%81%E6%9C%89%E7%9B%BC%E5%A4%B4%E3%80%81%E6%9C%89%E5%A5%94%E5%A4%B4%E3%80%82)

Comment: I never heard of 学头, 奔头 or 盼头, But there is a  common term 看头 with 头 meaning "worthy", and I've seen 听头 used in some contexts.  韋小寶：「這回書沒什麼聽頭」

Comment: @TangHo  I think 学头 and 奔头 are slogans created/adopted by China's 教育部 use the pattern of 盼头, which is a well-known term among Chinese.

Comment: @TangHo All three are commonly used in Sichuan Mandarin, so are many other words with 头. 头 seems to be a very active suffix. This is probably true in other dialects as well.

Comment: Please see this example: 这**年头**挣钱越来越少，没有**盼头**。

Comment: @PdotWang Just as in your answer - "附在某些名词后面，构成新的名词。如:木头;石头". Yet, it is also true that "附在某些动词后面，构成名词。如:念头."  Source: https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E5%A4%B4

Answer (score 0):

**头** is used to form nouns, such as 木头，石头. It means “kind of things”, “matters”, or “something related”.